# IndexOutOfRangeException in graphics filter code

Tags: .net, vb.net, math

I have some code that embosses a bitmap.
But somewhere in this code I have a flaw that causes an `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception.
I am unable to spot where I went wrong.

Does anybody see what I did wrong?

My current code is:

```
    Public Sub Emboss()
        OnFilterStarted()
        Dim bData = BitmapData.LockBits(b)

        Dim iByteDataLower As Integer = bData.ByteData.GetLowerBound(0)
        Dim iByteDataUpper As Integer = bData.ByteData.Length
        Dim iBmpWidth As Integer = bData.Bitmap.Width
        Dim iBmpHeight As Integer = bData.Bitmap.Height

        Const Level1 As Byte = 127
        Const Level2 As Byte = 255
        For ii = bData.ByteData.GetLowerBound(0) To bData.ByteData.Length - 1 Step 4
            If (ii + 4) Mod (bData.Bitmap.Width * 4) = 0 Then
                'right line - make gray
                bData.ByteData(ii) = Level1 'b
                bData.ByteData(ii + 1) = Level1 'g
                bData.ByteData(ii + 2) = Level1 'r
                Continue For
            End If
            Dim iY = bData.YFromOffset(ii)
            If iY = bData.Bitmap.Height - 1 Then
                'bottom line - make gray
                bData.ByteData(ii) = Level1 'b
                bData.ByteData(ii + 1) = Level1 'g
                bData.ByteData(ii + 2) = Level1 'r
                Continue For
            End If

            Dim OffsetPixelPointer = ii + ((bData.Bitmap.Width + 1) * 4)

            bData.ByteData(ii) = CByte(Math.Min(Math.Abs(CInt(bData.ByteData(ii)) - CInt(bData.ByteData(OffsetPixelPointer))) + Level1, Level2)) 'b
            bData.ByteData(ii + 1) = CByte(Math.Min(Math.Abs(CInt(bData.ByteData(ii + 1)) - CInt(bData.ByteData(OffsetPixelPointer + 1))) + Level1, Level2)) 'g
            bData.ByteData(ii + 2) = CByte(Math.Min(Math.Abs(CInt(bData.ByteData(ii + 2)) - CInt(bData.ByteData(OffsetPixelPointer + 2))) + Level1, Level2)) 'r
            'bData.ByteData(ii + 3) = 255 'a

        Next

        bData.UnlockBits()
        OnFilterFinished()
    End Sub
```

The error occurs in the line

```
bData.ByteData(ii) = CByte(Math.Min(Math.Abs(CInt(bData.ByteData(ii)) - CInt(bData.ByteData(OffsetPixelPointer))) + Level1, Level2)) 'b
```

`bData.ByteData.Length` is 65536
`OffsetPixelPointer` is 65796

It is clear that this doesn't work. `OffsetPixelPointer` exceeds `bData.ByteData.Length`, but I am not sure how this can happen.

I have looked over my code again and again, but I can't spot the error.
Did I make a casting mistake somewhere?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I suggest you have a night's sleep and then think about `For ii = bData.ByteData.GetLowerBound(0) To bData.ByteData.Length - 1 Step 4` in relation to `Dim OffsetPixelPointer = ii + ((bData.Bitmap.Width + 1) * 4)`. Also, you've declared `iByteDataLower` etc and not used them.

Comment: if you are going to reference data which is at offset `n + 2 + 127` (where n in the index counter, and 127 is level1) then you must set the loop to stop at least 129 steps sooner.